# pandas dataframe resample per day without date time index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe in pandas of the following form:

```
      timestamps         light
7   2004-02-28 00:58:45 150.88
26  2004-02-28 00:59:45 143.52
34  2004-02-28 01:00:45 150.88
42  2004-02-28 01:01:15 150.88
59  2004-02-28 01:02:15 150.88
```

Here note that the index is not the timestamps column. But I want to resample (or bin the data somehow) to reflect the average value of the light column per minute , hour, day etc.. I have looked into the `resample` method that pandas offers and it requires the dataframe to have a datatime index for the method to work (unless I've misunderstood this).

1. So my first question is, can I re-index the dataframe to have timestamps as the index (note that not each row has a unique timestamp and for each timestamp, there are about 30 rows with the same timestamp,each representing a sensor).
2. If not, is there some other way to possibly achieve another dataframe which has the average value of light per hour , per day , per month etc..?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right - need [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html), [`TimedeltaIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.html) or `PeriodIndex` else error:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

So you have to first [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) if original `index` is important:

```
print (df.reset_index().set_index('timestamps'))
                     index   light
timestamps                        
2004-02-28 00:58:45      7  150.88
2004-02-28 00:59:45     26  143.52
2004-02-28 01:00:45     34  150.88
2004-02-28 01:01:15     42  150.88
2004-02-28 01:02:15     59  150.88
```

if not only [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
print (df.set_index('timestamps'))
                      light
timestamps                 
2004-02-28 00:58:45  150.88
2004-02-28 00:59:45  143.52
2004-02-28 01:00:45  150.88
2004-02-28 01:01:15  150.88
2004-02-28 01:02:15  150.88
```

and then [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
print (df.reset_index().set_index('timestamps').resample('1D').mean())
            index    light
timestamps                
2004-02-28   33.6  149.408
```

Answer (score 16):

For pandas version 0.19.0 and newer you can use the `on` keyword:

```
df.resample('H', on='timestamps').mean()
```

Result:

```
                      light
timestamps                 
2004-02-28 00:00:00  147.20
2004-02-28 01:00:00  150.88
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an **approach to resample**.

You can use the following method to sample at `T` interval.

If original data was in every `minute`, your new resampled data will be at the `2 min` interval. 
You can use `3T, 4T....` any `T` value that fits your need.

`df_2T = df.resample('2T', on = 'timestamp').mean()`

**For hourly**
`df_hourly = df.resample('60T', on = 'timestamp').mean()`

**For daily**
`df_daily = df.resample('1440T', on = 'timestamp').mean()`

Note: One day has 60*24 = 1440 min